# How to find out which process runs a certain MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, process

I can see the processlist in an MySQL server by using `SHOW PROCESSLIST`, but I haven't found a way to find out which process/client/connection has submitted the query.

How can I find that out?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for that is not in the `Id/User/Host` columns of SHOW PROCESSLIST. Those columns identify the process. For example, you can use the `Id` in a KILL statement to terminate a query or a session. The `User` identifies the MySQL username. The `Host` tells you the client IP address or hostname from which  the app has connected.

Comment: @BillKarwin I usually use Postgres and it also tells me the name of the connecting client (e.g. psql or the name of the application that connects), and the Linux PID of the running process. I am missing that in this list.

Comment: MySQL has no idea what the client process is, by design. It only knows the client IP address. If you want MySQL to have all PostgreSQL's features (or likewise if you want PostgreSQL to have all MySQL's features), you're going to be disappointed.

Comment: @BillKarwin Thanks for this clear explanation, sounds like an answer to me ;-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MySQL Server only knows that the client authenticated, and the IP address of the host it appears to be connecting from. But nothing else about the client process.

Other RDBMS brands may have a protocol for transmitting client information, but MySQL doesn't support the same feature (likewise, MySQL may have some features that those other products don't have ;-).